# Azure Web app up giving 'No such file or directory error'

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cli, kudu

I'm trying to add my Node.js app to azure. I have logged in using the command az login. I ran the command

```
az webbapp up --name azuredemoapp
```

This is the error that I'm getting:-

```
The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p8t_6awn\knack\knack\cli.py", line 206, in invoke
File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p8t_6awn\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 603, in execute
File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p8t_6awn\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 661, in _run_jobs_serially
File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p8t_6awn\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 652, in _run_job
File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p8t_6awn\azure-cli\azure\cli\command_modules\appservice\commands.py", line 55, in _polish_bad_errors
File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p8t_6awn\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 631, in _run_job
File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p8t_6awn\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 306, in __call__
File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p8t_6awn\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\__init__.py", line 485, in default_command_handler
File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p8t_6awn\azure-cli\azure\cli\command_modules\appservice\custom.py", line 2783, in webapp_up
File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p8t_6awn\azure-cli\azure\cli\command_modules\appservice\_create_util.py", line 59, in get_runtime_version_details
File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p8t_6awn\azure-cli\azure\cli\command_modules\appservice\_create_util.py", line 192, in parse_netcore_version
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1196, in parse
tree.parse(source, parser)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 586, in parse
source = open(source, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

  To open an issue, please run: 'az feedback'
```

This is My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "azuredemodeploy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Rohan Shenoy",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely the way you are deploying your application, or the structure of the files in your project.

Please ensure you have a server.js or app.js in your project root.  You can also specify a custom startup script in packages.json.  See here for more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-local-git#prepare-your-repository

Comment: I have index.js, node_modules, package.json, package-lock.json files inside the folder

Comment: Do you have a start script configured in packages.json pointing to index.js?  The server expects you to have server.js or app.js.  If index.js is the startup then you need to configure it in packages.json.  Add `"start": "node index.js"` to packages.

Comment: Yes I have configured it exactly like that